# Where can I exchange Mongolian currency in Sydney?

Tags: money, australia, exchange, mongolia

I was given Mongolian money and I would like to exchange it within Australia. Where in Sydney can I exchange it?

Comment: A quick look around a couple of currency exchange comparison web sites suggests that there's nowhere in Sydney that will exchange it. This isn't really a surprise since it's not a common currency. What value of Tugrik do you have? 1,000,000₮ is roughly equivalent to AUD540. You might do better  selling your notes to a bank note collector.

Comment: Hi! How are you?  I'll try them, but can you please give me the addresses in Sydney as I've all ready known where to go in Australia. It's a 500 Tugrik.

Comment: 500₮ is worth about 27 Australian cents. I wouldn't waste time on it.

Comment: I totally will be keeping it and think that it's a silvernere

Comment: @CannonFodder  you should put that in as an answer!  Good one

Answer (score 1):

You cant change Mongolian Money out of Mongolia.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you provided some references!